# Automating web actions with Java

Tags: java

Can someone direct me to a Java tutorial that teaches how to interact with already existing websites (e.g. clicking, selecting from a drop down, entering text like login and password)?

Before I had any Java experience, I hired someone to write an application for me that automated daily tasks for all of my websites.  Now that I know how to code, I want to make changes to the application.  Unfortunately I don't have the source code.  I believe httpurlconnect is something that was mentioned.  Unfortunately, that's all I remember him talking about.

Any direction would be very much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) can do what you want. It's mainly used for automated testing but it's not limited to that use case. They even provide an [IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) you can use to create your scripts. It records the actions you perform and then you can play them back.

Comment: Thanks.  This looks great and I will check it out.  But I really want to know how to control browsing actions with Java code myself.  In the end something like Selenium will probably be what I use, but I wan't to learn how to code these actions myself.

Comment: That will be a much more difficult undertaking. Unless you just want to do it for fun I'd say there's no reason to reinvent the wheel. If you do want to do it for fun you'll need a lot more knowledge than what somebody is likely to provide in a single Stack Overflow answer. I'd suggest starting with the HTTPUrlConnection docs. Since all a browser does is make HTTP requests and receive HTTP responses you'd be able to replicate that. You're in for a lot of frustration, though. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. That's what I was asking for lol.  yes I do wan't to learn it from the ground up.  Not necessarily for "fun" but so that I understand the mechanics of it.  And I did not expect a one-off answer in here.  I was asking for a starting point which I could go from as you have so graciously provided. And frustration is what I'm looking for :) Ultimately I want to re-create application that was written for me.